# Grafana Alert Webhook - What are the possible states?

Tags: json, rest, grafana

I'm looking at the Grafana alert notification documentation:

http://docs.grafana.org/alerting/notifications/

And I gotta say it's quite sparse. The example web hook shows: `"state": "Alerting"`. From my tests, the actual value is `"alerting"` (lower case), and there's also an `"ok"` value for when it's all good. The dashboard also suggests there might be a "no data" state, although I haven't been able to repro this.

Is there any more detailed documentation, or better examples of what I can expect from the web hook JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible values are `ok`, `paused`, `alerting`, `pending`, `no_data`.

The documentation is now updated: http://docs.grafana.org/alerting/notifications/#webhook

Anything else you would like added to the docs for the webhook?

Comment: It would be nice to know what are the possible transitions between the alert states, specifically for the webhook; ideally in the form of DAG so one can get an idea of the lifecycle. This is useful when mapping these states to the states of incident systems consuming the webhook calls. Explaining what these states mean would help as well.